# how to validate the format of date dd/mm/yy or dd-mm-yy in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to restrict user to enter the format define in date-picker.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2" 
       placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="{{ " now "|date("d/m/Y") }}" 
       name="edu_assetbundle_assetallocation[condemedDate]" id="condemDate" />
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$("#condemDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be fixed by using `pattern`property in input field.

example :

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))" required />
```

For further read and patterns :

[HTML Date Patterns](http://html5pattern.com/Dates)

-Help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the problem by add the attribute pattern in your input type text.

Easy example:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required>
```

For more details and js validation you can see:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-date/